# Matlab singular matrix solver

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, singular

If matrices `AX=B`, and `A = 3x3`, `B=3x1`, and `A` is singular, and `B` has non zero numbers. Solve for `X`

Is this possible to solve for?

How can you solve for `X` in MATLAB, is it possible to solve this by hand?

I know that is `A` is singular because `det(A) =  0` and there is no inverse, but are these problems solvable or simply unsolvable?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [pseudo inverse](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pinv.html):

```
X = pinv(A) * B
```